# C getchar() misunderstanding

Tags: c, getchar

Can someone explain me the code ?? Wouldn't `d` be always equal to `c` ? I guess I don't really get this `getchar()` function.Why isn't `d` always equal to `c ?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    void test(int c);

    int main(void) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            test(c);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void test(int c) {
        int d;
        if (c == '/') {
            d = getchar();
            printf("%c", d);
        }
    }
```

Input:

> /*

Output:

> *

Comment: `void main()` is bad....

Comment: Why ?? You mean int main (void) is better ?? And than return 0; ??

Comment: And its not related to question by the way.

Comment: it's better, because it's correct. :)

Comment: I didnt know that.I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Why do you think `c` and `d`are equal? Have you read what `getchar` is doing?

Comment: @MuhamedCicak, `void main()` is not just "bad", it is *non-conforming*.  Implementations are permitted to accept additional implementation-specific signatures for `main()`, but the only ones defined by the standard are `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char **)`.  So yes, `int main(void)` is better.  The `main()` function is a special case, however, in that a `return` statement is altogether optional.

Comment: @JohnBollinger regarding that optional part, only if the intention is to return a value of 0.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand,thanks.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, well yes, the effect of execution reaching the closing brace of `main()` is the same as if a `return 0` statement were executed in `main()`.  That doesn't make the `return` statement any less optional, it just speaks to the semantics of omitting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. As mentioned in `C11`, chapter §7.21.7.6, The `getchar` function, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `getchar` function returns the **next character from the input stream** pointed to by
>   `stdin`. [...]

So, each call to `getchar()` will give you the ***next*** character input present in the input stream. So, when `c == '/'` condition is met, it will read the next entry and store into `d`, it need not be the same as `c`, anyway.

Comment: I didn't know that `getchar()` returns **next** character input.Thanks for the explanation.Now everything is pretty clear.